# Java Swing JPanel paintComponents never called

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm having an issue with a JPanel and I don't get what's going on. So I have a JFrame with a init function, that create a custom JPanel called GamePanel, and the strange thing is it never goes in the paintComponents function, even if I use repaint on the object.

Here is my code when I initialize the JPanel (in a JFrame):

```
this.gamePanel = new GamePanel(this.grid, this);
this.panel.add(this.gamePanel, constraints);
```

And the JPanel itself:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private final int SQUARE_SIZE = 50;

    private Grid grid;
    private final GameView gameView;

    public GamePanel(Grid grid, GameView gameView) {
        this.gameView = gameView;

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    }

    public void setGrid(Grid grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(grid.getSizeX() * SQUARE_SIZE, grid.getSizeY() * SQUARE_SIZE));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("test");

        if (this.grid != null) {

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            double thickness = 3;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float) thickness));

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    int x = SQUARE_SIZE * i;
                    int y = SQUARE_SIZE * j;

                    g2.drawRect(x, y, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);

                    if(this.grid.getSquareState(x, y) != 0) {
                        char[] tmp = ("" + this.grid.getSquareState(x, y)).toCharArray();
                        g2.drawChars(tmp, 0, 1, x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: (the whole JFrame)

```
public class GameView extends JFrame {

    private CustomSocket socket;
    private JPanel panel;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private JLabel listPlayers;
    private JLabel playerPlaying;
    private Grid grid;

    public GameView(CustomSocket socket) {   
        this.socket = socket;
        this.setTitle("TicTacToe - Client");

        this.setSize(600, 480);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.init();
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.play();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints =new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;

        // Grid
        this.gamePanel = new GamePanel(this.grid, this);
        this.panel.add(this.gamePanel, constraints);

        // Labels
        constraints.gridy += 1; 
        this.listPlayers = new JLabel();
        this.panel.add(this.listPlayers, constraints);

        constraints.gridy += 1; 
        this.playerPlaying = new JLabel();
        this.panel.add(this.playerPlaying, constraints);

        this.setContentPane(this.panel);
    }

    private void play() {
        String[] tmp = this.socket.getData().split(";");

        this.grid = new Grid(Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]), Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]));

        String players = "";
        for(int i = 2; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            players += tmp[i] + " ";
        }

        this.listPlayers.setText(players);

        boolean notFinished = true;
        while(notFinished) {
            String[] gridData = this.socket.getData().split(";");
            for(int i = 1; i < gridData.length; i++) {
                String[] gridRow = gridData[i].replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",");


                for(int j = 0; j < gridRow.length; j++) {
                    this.grid.setSquareState(i - 1, j, Integer.parseInt(gridRow[j]));
                }
            }

            this.gamePanel.repaint();

            String playerPlaying = this.socket.getData().split(";")[0];

            if(playerPlaying != this.socket.getUsername()) {
            }
            notFinished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use paintComponent, not paintComponents

Comment: I tried with both functions and unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Why is it that of your [7 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6743005/florian-merle), only **one** has an accepted answer? SO not working out for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.panel.add(this.gamePanel, constraints);
```

You add the component to a panel, but the panel doesn't have a preferred size. Since its size is (0, 0) there is nothing to paint so the method is never called.

All Swing components are responsible for determining their own preferred size.  Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your custom component. Then the layout manager can set the proper size/location of the component.

And `paintComponent(...)` is the proper method to override and don't forget the `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first statement to make sure the background gets cleared.

Comment: Well, adding the getPreferredSize() method didn't solved the issue, but if I change the dimension it definitly make the window bigger.

Comment: Edit: I added the whole code from the JFrame in my original post

Comment: @FlorianMerle You missed my last point, which has been made twice now. Also, who knows if your Socket is causing problems. Maybe the code is blocking waiting for input. Do some more debugging to determine is the logic flow is correct.

Comment: The code isn't blocking waiting for an input, I checked, and also I changed the method from paintComponents(...) to paintComponent(...). So I don't get what's going on.

Comment: @FlorianMerle, there is nothing special going on. Create a simple example with just a JFrame and a panel. Draw a simple rectangle on the panel. Get this simple code working first before writing your game. Once it works then do more complicated painting. Then start to add game logic. In other words test your code one step at a time instead of writing the whole application before starting testing. If you have a problem with this basic code then post it in the forum. This is called an [mcve].